# latex - superimposed figure in pdf file

Tags: pdf

Figure is superimposed over text in pdf document created from a dvi file.

Not superimposed in ps document created from the same dvi file.

```
\begin{figure}
\scalebox{0.9}{\includegraphics{pbar.eps}} \caption{Illustration of nonequilibrium hyperplane probabilities for the single particle decay problem; $N_{Max}=5$.  Time is made dimensionless here through a characteristic time constant $t_0$.}
\end{figure}
```

Here are my latex headings:

```
\documentstyle[12pt, graphics]{article}
\def\baselinestretch{2.0}
\textheight 10.2in \topmargin -0.8in \textwidth 6.7in \oddsidemargin
-0.2in \evensidemargin -0.1in
\parskip 0.20in
\begin{document}
```

I can ps to pdf to fix this, but that eliminates my top margin somehow and is therefore not an acceptable fix.

Comment: Adjusting these lowlevel commands yourself is usually never a good idea. Use package `geometry` or `typearea` for page layout and package `setspace` for the linespread.

Comment: Oh, and are you really using LaTeX 2.09?

Comment: As @MaxNoe implies, the `\documentstyle` command is from LaTeX 2.09, and I think it was  recommended to stop using that about 20 years ago.

Comment: If changing that `\documentstyle` is not possible, try to explicitly specify the paper size during conversion to preserve the margins. Use `dvips -t a4 -Ppdf file.dvi` (change a4 to letter if wanted), then `ps2pdf file.ps`

Comment: I use winedt 7.0 and the latest miketex.

Comment: thanks be to all of the smart aleck's in the world - no help as usual.  just wise-a** comments.  fixed this myself.  I found that the eps figure file created by matlab may be the problem. If I save the figure as a pdf in matlab then convert it to eps using acrobat pro I have no problem.  Must be some encoding of the eps figure file from matlab.

Comment: Wow, that's rude. You were the one seeking for help and it has not been longer than 2 hours. Maybe  a little patience for people trying to help you on a completely voluntary basis?

Comment: @pete: You do have a point, and I guess I could have left out posting my previous comment, or at least tried to make it a bit more constructive. Sorry about that. On the other hand, MaxNoe also has a point in his last comment.

Comment: Yes, sorry for being snapish at the 20 year old comment.  The problem is not with the document class statement.  it appears that the problem is just  with Matlab generated *.eps files.  All other eps files are fine.Something must be embedded in the eps file to retain the graphical space I am guessing.  I am not an expert on *.eps files obviously. Others may have similar problems, but the quick fix is to save Matlab figures in pdf format and then convert to eps.  I am not sure this is a Latex problem, but there may be some clever way to fix it in Latex.

Comment: The 20 year old comment was serious. LaTeX2e was introduced in 1994. Since then you are supposed to to use `\documentclass` and not `\documentstyle`. Also there is really no point anymore in producing dvi files if you end product should be a pdf file. Use pdflatex. Just give it a try ;)

Answer (score 2):

The comments contain useful information even if not responsible for the particular problem you asked about in this question. You will have fewer problems if you use the correct syntax and use something like `geometry` as an interface for setting up the page layout.

Here is your code modified with some comments:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}% LaTeX2e uses \documentclass
\usepackage{graphicx}% for \includegraphics
\usepackage{setspace}% for double spacing
\usepackage[textheight=10.2in, textwidth=6.7in, inner=0.8in, top=.2in]{geometry}% for page layout (check for equivalence - can't test with a fragment of code only)
\setlength\parskip{0.20in}% consider using package parskip if you want no paragraph indent either; otherwise, maybe use package parskip and then set parindent to override its setting it to 0
\begin{document}
\doublespacing% double-spacing
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{pbar}% better not to include the extension; \includegraphics has a scale key so no need for an additional command
\caption{Illustration of nonequilibrium hyperplane probabilities for the single particle decay problem; $N_{Max}=5$.  Time is made dimensionless here through a characteristic time constant $t_0$.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```